# VirtualHost - Linux doesn't work

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

i got following code works fine

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but when i put * and other in server i doesn't take to the file instead take me to root directory

this doesn't work

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com
ServerName other.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

please help me with it

Comment: see http://serverfault.com

Comment: user460024, what is the version of your Linux and Apache? Can you ping the host "other.domain.com" or "something.domain.com"? (there should be corresponding DNS "*" record.) Why you didn't set Alias for the "domain.com", and does www.domain.com works?

Comment: yes domain.com works, i have set wildcard subdomain for project...that what seems to be requirements.